# I found a question that is a mix of two different questions. Is it a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

The question [How to change country in Mac OS X?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9392) is asking how to find the Torrc for MacOS X and how to change the Torrc file to only have exit nodes from a specific country.

However, there are answers for both parts of this question:

- A duplicate of the first part asking about how to find the Torrc for MacOS X can be found here: [torrc on a Mac?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/901/)
- A duplicate of exiting from a specific country can be found here: [Can I exit from a specific country or node?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node)

Basically, this question has duplicates for both parts. So should it be closed as a duplicate or not? Also, is there a way to classify this question as a duplicate of both those questions?

Comment: I can answer this part, at least: "Also, is there a way to classify this question as a duplicate of both those questions?" – Yes, there is. Users who have a gold badge in one of the tags on the question (as well as site mods) can close the question as a duplicate singlehandedly; they can also edit the duplicates list on such a question to add links to other questions as well, and/or reorder the list of duplicates. [See this MSE post for more info.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/335251)

Comment: Surely if has two parts, the question should simply be closed as *Too Broad*.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the [question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/9392/88) needs a good answer on how to find the `torrc` in a macOS system. Currently the answer deals with Vidalia. This is not helpful for people, because Vidalia is not distributed anymore.

So if the question had a good general answer, I'd propose to close the other [question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/901/88) as duplicate and so point it to the first question.

The [question about exiting from a certain country](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/733/88) is more a general question which only in part has something to do with macOS. So I would not touch it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the input! After rethinking this, perhaps we don't have to do anything really because both of the answers to [How to change country in Mac OS X?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9392) seems somewhat old so until a new answer comes, I don't think we should close the other question. So right now, I don't think anything has to be done really, but we should wait until a better answer appears.